# N-tier Object Parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, n-tier-architecture

I am struggling on n-tier concept. At first I had this concept that my domain entity would be shared across my 3 layer been ( DAL, BLL, Service). But was recently told this was an old concept and didn't really follow SOLID concept. and instead was told to create and object for each layer.

```
Service
  ObjectService
Business
  ObjectBus
DAL
  Object
```

Which yes Service still depends on business, business depends on dal and so on. However I am not to sure how to pass my object or how to create them.

Lets say at my data layer I have a person.cs with the following properties

```
public class Person:Base
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string middleName { get; set; }
}
```

In my business object should I create a business method like this

```
Boolean CreatePerson(userrole r,string f, string l, string m);
```

Or should I do something like this

```
Boolean CreatePerson(PersonHandler pmo);
```

Where I have a class PersonHandler

```
public class PersonHandler
{
    public UserRole r { get; set; };
    public Person p { get; set; };
}
```

In this case userrole is just extra properties that the business layer would need. I like creating an object for the business layer, as I could change all the properties associated to this object easier, however I feel I still need access to the domain entities ( Person ), which I was told this was bad. But If I create a set of properties for each object I just feel this would be redundant . what if in the future I change my person at DAL, wouldnt that mean I have to change every parameter going up the ladder?

Here a sample more in def of my structure folder

[image]

This is my structure for DAL.

[image]

Comment: it is clear that using a methods like `Boolean CreatePerson(userrole r,string f, string l, string m);` is a bad idea. Using DAL layer clases as input parameters in BL should not be a problem.

Comment: how are you doing your data access?  entity frameowrk, nhibernate, some orm?  are you doing cqrs?

Comment: I am using Entity framework

Comment: I don't see why having a separate common assembly containing entities would be an issue. But anyway, you basically need to do a bunch of mapping from DAL entitites to business DAOs inside the business layer (which will likely have the same interface and can be automapped), so that the service layer only uses BL DAOs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You structure seems like complete overkill.  You state you are using entity Framework.  This is an ORM is is supposed to map you business entities/objects to data structures and should be used as such.

Why not create you domain using EF code first with attributes to map the domain entities back to the sql table?  I'm assuming there's sql at the back end.  keep your business logic in your domain model or you risk the chance of creating an [anemic mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_domain_model)l

For the front end, I would define viewmodels that represent the screen/view you are presenting to the user since this is separate from the domain objects.  Then populate the view models from your domain objects.

Comment: Because I am using Entity Framework your suggesting that i create a domain layer that has poco object, and that I could shared among layers? I was told this wasn't SOLID because a programmer could somehow directly set it from the service layer or so ( my understanding)

Comment: We also prefer to have a DAL which keeps the ORM wrapped in a repo pattern, simply because repos are easier to inject/mock without creating any dependencies on the ORM (EF/NHibernate or whatever) throughout the business layer. In theory, ORM will help you easily replace your RDBMS with some other, but in practice it doesn't really work that way, and sometimes you even need to hack some actual SQL for performance or whatever reasons, and using the ORM framework directly inside your business layer means this is where you will end up writing SQL code.

Comment: I also use the repos around my domain objects for that exact reason.  you can split the poco object with the mapping for better separation and place you custom sql in the mapping, but there isn't a full separate Person at the data acess level, there's a PersonMap mapping object.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the `Person` type is specific to the data layer. The business layer (and others) have no idea what a `Person` is. The business layer has it's own idea of "person", and should have a separate class, possibly with any extra properties you might want. That's the whole point of having multiple layers.

Now, you cannot move your object directly across the layers. You need a mapper between adjacent layers, which would take an object of, say, `DataLayer.Person` and convert it into `BusinessLayer.Person`.

You can either build your own mapper, or use a tool like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/).

Comment: Business layer will likely *know* what a `Person` is, if it depends on DAL.

Comment: If you are working with EF, that should take care of mapping you business person to sql tables.  why would you need a data layer person?

Comment: Friom this approach which seem to make sense would I create a folder called Automapper, and inside see PersonMap class which would allow me to directly talk to the dal and map it

Comment: @Jseb: the `Person` class in the DAL layer must be a `public` class. There is no point in creating an intermediate layer. Doesn't your typical DAL method look something like: `Person GetPersonByName(string name)`?

Comment: @Groo Yes I do have this but I also have method like creation void Add(Person entity); I think it make sense to send the person when these method exists, if you change a property in the future it would be harder to go around and change everything

Comment: @Jseb: I didn't understand that last comment ("send the person when these method exists"). I am claiming that's 1) your entities should simply be in a separate assembly shared between DAL and Business Layer or exposed by DAL, and 2) creating an intermediate layer between DAL and Business Layer makes no sense, unless you also intend to proxy all your DAL methods inside this layer to use these intermediate mapped objects.

Comment: So in other words following this http://dotnetdaily.net/tutorials/n-tier-architecture-asp-net/ architecture its totally acceptable still in today architecture. I was told no, but your saying its insane to not follow this approach?

Comment: I am saying it's insane to add an additional layer between DAL and BL, i.e. either everyone knows about model entities, but only BL knows how to persist them through DAL, or you do the mapping inside BL (not in the intermediate layer), but there are little practical benefits in adding this mapping. However, in the link you provided, I don't see why DAL or Service layer should know anything about MVC models.